Custom Sidebar Table of Contents in Beamer
I'm working with a blank Beamer presentation template and want to recreate a sidebar similar to one shown in the image below. Unlike typical Beamer sidebars that extend to the page's edge, this one is part of a custom frame. I'd like the sidebar to display boxed sections with sharp drop shadows. The current section should be highlighted by a red shadow, while the current subsection should be bolded and appear on a white horizontal strip. Subsections from other sections should remain hidden until the presentation reaches that specific section, at which point they should appear in a dropdown list in the sidebar (e.g. in the image, we're on SO so subsections of SO are shown in the sidebar, but subsections of Section Two and Section Three are not).
Note: By 'subsection' I really mean slide titles.
How can I implement this effect in LaTeX? Any help would be appreciated.

\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{
            lmodern,
            babel,
            amsmath,
            eurosym
           }
\definecolor{darkpastelgreen}{rgb}{0.01, 0.75, 0.24}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \fill[sharp corners,fill=darkpastelgreen]
    ($ (current page.north west) + (0.4cm,-0.4cm) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.south east) + (-0.4cm,0.4cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \fill[sharp corners,color=white]
    ($ (current page.north west) + (0.5cm,-0.5cm) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.south east) + (-2cm,0.5cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.8cm, text margin right=0.85cm} % Reduce side margins



\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\color{black}\bfseries\insertframetitle 

\nointerlineskip

\bigskip

} 
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{0cm}}{\vspace*{-0.4cm}}
\addtolength{\headsep}{0.6cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{}
\frametitle{A Subsection}

Slide content goes here...

\end{frame}

\end{document}


I'd start with the "typical" beamer sidebar and draw a white frame on top of it.

To give you something to start with:
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{fancybox}

\useoutertheme[height=0pt,right]{sidebar}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=green!50!brown}
\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar shaded}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in sidebar}{bg=white,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in sidebar shaded}{bg=white,fg=black}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@sidebarformat#1#2#3{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\beamer@sidebarwidth,leftskip=#1,rightskip=1ex plus1fil,vmode]{#2}
    \vbox{}%
    \centering
    #3\par%
    \vbox{}%
    \vskip-1.5ex%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\setbeamertemplate{section in sidebar shaded}{%
  \vbox{%
    \vskip1ex%
    \beamer@sidebarformat{3pt}{section in sidebar shaded}{\shadowbox{\insertsectionhead}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsubsectionhead}
Slide content goes here...
\end{frame}

\end{document}


